# Numbers for iPad If checkbox false then clear value so when ticked again cell is blank for next manually input value

Tags: numbers, iwork

I have 2 tables on top of each other. Table 1 contains a checkbox in cell F80, when ticked its cell background colour changes to dark green. On top is Table 2-1 which has text and outlines in sheet background colour (almost white) so that it is invisible until the checkbox background is activated by ticking the box. Table 2-1 contains a cell (C2), in which the user enters a numerical value. The cell background is the almost-white of the sheet background with black text so input area is highly visible when checkbox ticked.
I need the Table 2-1 cell to be cleared when checkbox is unticked so there’s not a black number floating in the middle of nowhere, and so that the user can tick the box again to add more, and again and again. The input cell in Table 2-1 HAS to remain manually editable, so the function cannot go in that cell.
Is this possible?
If it’s not possible does anyone have an alternate method to try, please?

Thanks for reading this.

My code:

```
IF(AND(F80=FALSE,'Table 2-1'::C2≥1),"when checkbox (f80 in table 1) is clicked off, clear the value in 'Table 2-1'::C2, so that when checkbox is ticked again the cell is empty and user can add new value")
```

[image: is this possible?]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but you won't be able to bypass the top table for selecting the bottom table.